# Have a blob for a wav file on client side, how do I send it as a wav file to the server?

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, audio

So I am using recorder.js to generate a blob for a wav file, an example blob looks something like this `"blob:b99aada2-955c-4fcf-a0ad-da5bb377f4b2"`.

I'm sending it to a server running django. I need some way to take this blob data, and store it on my server as a wav file.

My code is based on this example here: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html Where instead of downloading the file, I'd like to submit that file in a HTML form somehow. The download anchor looks something like this:

`<a id="save" href="blob:14444ab4-61c1-4fa9-9b6a-83db4ea73e7e" download="myRecording02.wav">`

I'm very new to this side of JS, so any help would be very much appreciated. I've spent hours trying to find something that works.

What I'm trying to achieve overall is have visitors to my site record a message, which is sent to my server.

Comment: Hi capcom, I am trying to achieve the same thing. Have you got the answer?